# Mean Stack: Cannot fetch the data from mongodb to frontend; Error:Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, mongodb

Developing a MEAN stack app. Using Angular 6,Node-10.3.0. I am trying to fetch the data from mongodb model and display that data to HTML page. But i am making a small mistake i think. Tried to search for the same but could not resolve the error.

**Error is**

```
SyntaxError: clients.component.ts 
  Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.push../node_modules/@angular/http/fesm5/http.js.Body.json
```

Here is the code **client.service**

```
getClients() {
        let headers = new Headers ({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/admin/clients', options).pipe(
            map((response: Response) => response));
  }
```

here is the **client-component file**

```
export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit {

clients: any[];

  constructor( private clientService: ClientService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  this.getAllClients();
  }

  getAllClients(){
      this.clientService.getClients().subscribe((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          this.clients = res;
        }, err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }

}
```

here is the **`html file`**

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>S.No.</th>
        <th>Client Name</th>
        <th>Client Phone No</th>
        <th>Client Address</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let client of clients">
          <th>1</th>
          <th>{{ client.clientName}}</th>
           <th>{{ client.clientPhoneNo }}</th>
           <th>{{ client.clientAddress }}</th>
      </tr>
</table>
```

I think there is a small mistake, please help me in the same.

Here is **`server.js`**

```
var client = require('./server/routes/clients');

app.use('/api', client.router);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/mean-travels')));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/mean-travels/index.html'));
});

app.post('/admin/clients/add', client.saveclient);

app.get('/admin/clients', client.getclient);
```

---

here is the **`getclient route function`**

```js
function getclient(req, res, next){
    console.log("finding all clients");
    Client.find({}, function(err, clients){
        if (err) return next(err);
        console.log(clients);
        res.json(clients);
    });
};

module.exports= {getclient};
```

**here i am getting an error `typeerror:cannot read the property of 'json' of undefined`**.

Comment: Looks like your sending back HTML, not JSON. So your JSON parse of course will fail.

Comment: @sneha_h could you able to console the `res` if yes then what is the output of that console?

Comment: Might be something wrong with MongoDB query or related to that!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale no its not fetching the `res`, its giving the error `err` in console.

Comment: @sneha_h yes exactly!

Comment: it could be: >What you think is supposed to be JSON, starts with a "<" as the first character, and JSON doesn't ever start with a "<". Most likely you are receiving either html or xml.

Comment: here is the query `function getclient(req, res, next){
    Client.find(function(err, clients){
        if (err) return next(err);
        console.log(clients);
        res.json(clients);
    });
};` not getting the clients.

Comment: Is that Mongo DB's query?

Comment: yes Client.find()?

Comment: We know nothing about the server-side code. What does Node's `/admin/clients` route look like?

Comment: i think the problem is with the route `app.get('/admin/clients)`, its not working.

Comment: @sneha_h yeah, that's because you wrote `app.get('*'` to return an index.html file, so it's going to return that file for every single GET request.